# UITableView unresponsive to gestures and not populating cells with data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a UITableView programmatically and set all of its attributes, but the data from my NSMutableArray will not populate the cells and the cells do nothing when tapped. Any insight appreciated, thanks!

Clayton

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    list = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height * .3333, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * .6667) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    list.delegate = self;
    list.dataSource = self;
    list.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    list.scrollEnabled = YES;
    list.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    list.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    list.hidden = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:list];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:list];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [favorites count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *Cell = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:Cell];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[global sharedInstance].favorites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.hidden = NO;
    cell.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:cell];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"selected %ld row", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: Is `favorites` not `nil`? Does it have any objects in it?

Comment: @rmaddy it changes. it can, but doesn't have to. Whether or not it does the result if the same though.

Comment: If `favorites` is `nil` or empty, then the table will have no rows. Simple enough. Is the table empty when `favorites` has items in it?

Comment: It is but it should not be, that's the point.

Comment: It is what? Please be clear.

Comment: Favorites has items but table is still empty.

Comment: Update your question showing how favorites is set and where you call reloadData on the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks, the problem was with the data transferring from my singleton array of favorites to my local array (which was previously empty). Much obliged :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of viewDidLoad method, just add this:

> [list reloadData];